# Как сохранить файловую структуру при использовании asset/resource в Webpack 5

Tags: webpack

Проекте изображения храняться в директории images и разделены по подпапкам. Как при сборке проекта сохранить в dist такое же дерево как и в src при использовании asset/resource в Webpack 5?

Если я использую такие настройки, то все изображения сохраняются в одну папку

```
rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'images/[name]-[hash][ext]',
        }
      },
    ],
  },
```

А если я добавляю [path] в имя фала, то все изображения попадают в dist/src  - dist/src/images

```
  {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: '[path][name]-[hash][ext]',
        }
 },
```

Мне не нужна в dist ещё папка src в которой лежат изображения,
Как можно убрать имя папки "src" из пути файла, что бы файловая струтура повторяла папку images которая в  src?